# ALTER SESSION SET CONSTRAINTS = DEFERRED equivalent in EDB/ Postgres

Tags: postgresql, oracle, edb

What will be equivalent of following query in EDB Postgres / Open source Postgres?

```
ALTER SESSION SET CONSTRAINTS = DEFERRED
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need:

```
set constraints all deferred;
```

Source: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-set-constraints.html